# Goniometry, application of duplication and bisection formulas: question $2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have the following exercise $n$. $161$.

[image]

I have thought that the $A\hat{D}C=2A\hat{C}D$ and if $A\hat{C}D=\alpha$, we get, with $\sin \alpha=\dfrac{3\sqrt 5}{5}$,

$$\sin(2\alpha)=2\sin\alpha\cos \alpha=2\cdot\dfrac{3\sqrt 5}{5}\cdot \frac 45 \neq  \frac{3\sqrt {13}}{13}.$$

I have not used the angle $\hat{B}$. I don't know how to utilize some hidden geometric property of the triangle other than the one I have indicated at the beginning. How should one proceed to get both results? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $\;\sin ADC = \sin (A+C)/2 = \cos B/2\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Why $\sin A\hat DC = \frac{\sin (A+C)}{2}= \cos \frac B2$? What is the propriety?

Comment: $\angle ADC=180^\circ-A/2-C/2$

Comment: @Sebastiano $ADC = \pi - \frac{A}{2} - \frac{C}{2} = \pi - \frac{A+C}{2}\;$ and $\;\frac{A+C}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{B}{2}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Now I have understood.  thank you very much. Another question why $\sin A\hat DC = \frac{\sin (A+C)}{2}$?

Comment: @Sebastiano That's not where the parentheses fall, what I meant is $\,\sin ADC = \sin \frac{A+C}{2}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Could give me a complete answer. I am actually tired and I am not able to do an answer editing the question. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note it's generally not true that $A\hat{D}C=2A\hat{C}D$. Instead, first let

$$x = \measuredangle CAD = \measuredangle DAB, \;\; y = \measuredangle ACD = \measuredangle BCD \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Using $\cos(2z)=2\cos^2(z)-1$ from [List of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities), and that $x+y\lt 90^{\circ}$ so $\cos(x+y)\gt 0$, we then have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\cos \hat{B} & = \cos(180^{\circ}-2x-2y) \\
\frac{5}{13} & = -\cos(2(x+y)) \\
\frac{5}{13} & = 1-2\cos^2(x+y) \\
-\frac{8}{13} & = -2\cos^2(x+y) \\
\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}} & = \cos(x+y)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Therefore, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sin A\hat{D}C & = \sin(180^{\circ}-x-y) \\
& = \sin(x+y) \\
& = \sqrt{1-\cos^2(x+y)} \\
& = \sqrt{\frac{13}{13} - \frac{4}{13}} \\
& = \frac{3}{\sqrt{13}} \\
& = \frac{3\sqrt{13}}{13}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Also,

$$\cos A\hat{C}D = \cos(y) = \frac{4}{5} \;\;\to\;\; \sin(y) = \sqrt{1-\cos^2(y)} = \frac{3}{5} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

From \eqref{eq2A}, we get

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}} = \cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y) = \frac{4\cos(x)-3\sin(x)}{5} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

With \eqref{eq3A},

$$\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}} = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y) = \frac{4\sin(x)+3\cos(x)}{5} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Next, $-3$ times \eqref{eq5A} plus $4$ times \eqref{eq6A} gives

$$\frac{6}{\sqrt{13}} = \frac{25\sin(x)}{5} \;\;\to\;\; \sin(x) = \frac{6}{5\sqrt{13}} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Also, $4$ times \eqref{eq5A} plus $3$ times \eqref{eq6A} results in

$$\frac{17}{\sqrt{13}} = \frac{25\cos(x)}{5} \;\;\to\;\; \cos(x) = \frac{17}{5\sqrt{13}} \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Thus, this gives that

$$\tan C\hat{A}D = \tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \frac{\frac{6}{5\sqrt{13}}}{\frac{17}{5\sqrt{13}}} = \frac{6}{17} \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

This doesn't match the stated answer of $\frac{7}{9}$, but I've checked my work several times without seeing anything which is incorrect. Regardless, the procedure I've shown above can be used to get the correct answer.

---

**Update:** The OP has posted [Goniometry exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4657054/602049), with this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657098/602049) there confirming my result of $\frac{6}{17}$ in \eqref{eq9A}.