# Goniometry exercise

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have this exercise n. 161

[image]

Where am I going wrong with my steps?

**My solution**:
We know that $\hat A+\hat B+\hat C=\pi \implies \frac{\hat A+\hat C}2=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\hat B}{2}$.
Hence
$$\sin A\hat D C=\sin\biggl(\pi-\frac{\hat A+\hat C}2\biggr)=\sin\biggl(\pi -\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\hat B}{2}\biggr)=\sin\biggl(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\hat B}{2}\biggr)=\cos\frac{\hat B}{2}$$
But $\cos\frac{\hat B}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{5}{13}}2}=\frac{3\sqrt{13}}{13}$.

$$\tan C\hat A D=\frac{\sin C\hat A D}{\cos C\hat A D}$$

$C\hat A D=\pi-A\hat CD-A\hat DC$, but $\sin(C\hat A D)=\sin(\pi-(A\hat CD+A\hat DC))=\sin(A\hat CD+A\hat DC)$.

$$\sin(A\hat CD+A\hat DC)=\sin A\hat CD\cos A\hat DC+\sin A\hat DC\cos A\hat CD=$$
$$=\sqrt{1-\cos^2A\hat CD}\sqrt{1-\sin^2A\hat DC}+\frac{3\sqrt{13}}{13}\frac 45$$
$$=\sqrt{1-\frac{16}{25}}\, \cdot \sqrt{1-\frac{9}{13}}+\frac{3\sqrt{13}}{13}\frac 45=\frac{6}{5\sqrt{13}}+\frac{12}{5\sqrt{13}}$$

For $\cos C\hat A D$ the same steps.
$$\cos(C\hat A D)=\cos(\pi-(A\hat CD+A\hat DC))=$$$$-\cos(A\hat CD+A\hat DC) =-\cos A\hat CD\cos A\hat DC+\sin A\hat DC\sin A\hat CD$$$$=-\frac 45\cdot \frac{\sqrt 5}{13}+\frac{3\sqrt{13}}{13}\cdot \frac 35$$
Wtih my steps $\tan C\hat A D \neq 6/17$.

Comment: First mistake: $\sin(A\hat CD+A\hat DC) \color{red}\ne \sin A\hat CD\cos A\hat DC+\sin A\hat DC\cos A\hat DC$, rather $\sin(A\hat CD+A\hat DC) = \sin A\hat CD\cos A\hat DC+\sin A\hat DC\cos A\hat CD$

Comment: @SandipanSamanta Thank you very much: it is a typo.

Comment: Second mistake: $\cos A\hat D C=\cos\left(\pi-\frac{\hat A+\hat C}2\right)=\cos\left(\pi -\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\hat B}{2}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\hat B}{2}\right)=-\sin\frac{\hat B}{2} = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$, whereas you used $\cos A\hat D C=\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$ in calculating $\sin C\hat A D$ and used $\cos A\hat D C=\frac{\sqrt5}{13}$ in calculating $\cos C\hat A D$

Comment: (TIL "goniometry" is a word)

Comment: @SandipanSamanta But $\cos A\hat D C=\sqrt{1-\sin^2A\hat DC}$?

Comment: These two changes will result in $\sin C\hat AD = \frac{6}{5\sqrt{13}}$ and $\cos C\hat AD = \frac{17}{5\sqrt{13}}$

Comment: @SandipanSamanta Please, can you put an answer, kindly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $\hat A+\hat B+\hat C=\pi \implies \frac{\hat A+\hat C}2=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\hat B}{2}$.

Hence
$$\sin A\hat D C=\sin\biggl(\pi-\frac{\hat A+\hat C}2\biggr)=\sin\biggl(\pi -\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\hat B}{2}\biggr)=\sin\biggl(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\hat B}{2}\biggr)=\cos\frac{\hat B}{2}$$
But $\cos\frac{\hat B}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{5}{13}}2}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}$.

Note that it is not clear if $A \hat DC$ is acute or obtuse, which will affect the sign of the cosine term. So, $\cos A\hat D C$ may be equal to either one of $\pm \sqrt{1-\sin^2 A\hat D C}$. Instead we can use
$$\cos A\hat D C=\cos\biggl(\pi-\frac{\hat A+\hat C}2\biggr)=\cos\biggl(\pi -\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\hat B}{2}\biggr)=\cos\biggl(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\hat B}{2}\biggr)=-\sin\frac{\hat B}{2}$$

Now, $\frac{\hat B}{2}$ is acute because $\hat B$ is an angle of the triangle. So, $\sin \frac{\hat B}{2} = \sqrt{1-\cos^2 \frac{\hat B}{2}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$

Then, $\cos A \hat CD = \frac45$ and $\sin A \hat CD = \frac35$

and $\cos A \hat DC = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$ and $\sin A \hat DC = \frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}$

$$\sin(C\hat A D)=\sin(\pi-(A\hat CD+A\hat DC))=\sin(A\hat CD+A\hat DC) \\ =\sin A\hat CD\cos A\hat DC+\sin A\hat DC\cos A\hat CD \\
=\frac{6}{5\sqrt{13}}$$

$$\cos(C\hat A D)=\cos(\pi-(A\hat CD+A\hat DC))=-\cos(A\hat CD+A\hat DC) \\
=-\cos A\hat CD\cos A\hat DC+\sin A\hat DC\sin A\hat CD \\
=\frac{17}{5\sqrt{13}}$$

This gives $\tan C\hat A D = 6/17$.

Comment: Your result matches that in my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4656503/602049) to a similar previous question, where I used a somewhat different method.